# using webpack for css Error:Module parse failed

Tags: javascript, webpack, css-loader

I'm using `Webpack` in my project.

webpack.config.js:

```
moule.exports ={
...
module:{
rules:[
{
test:/\.css$/,
use:[
{loader:"css-loader"}
{loader:"style-loader"}
]
}
...
]}
```

Everything except this works fine:

css:

```
pre[class*="language-"]{
background:#f5f2f0
}
```

error:

```
Module parse failed:Unexpected token (7:10)
You may need appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. see https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders 
*/
> pre[class*="language-"] {
background:#f5f2f0
```

can someone tell me what should I add in my webpack.config.js file to help the css file run?

Answer (score 1):

change the `use` array in your `webpack.config.js` file to

```
use: [
  "style-loader",
  "css-loader",
  "postcss-loader",
  },
]
```

Add a `postcss.config` file to your root folder with this content

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [require("precss"), require("autoprefixer")],
};
```

Specifically in this order.

You can read more about `postcss-loader` here: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/postcss-loader/
Also, ensure you install these new loaders.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
but I don't know what plugins I have to put on `Options` at `postcss.config.file`.
using that loader without putting value in `Options` - do nothing

Comment: I updated my comment to include your need to add a `postcss.config` file. There is more about this on the documentation.

Comment: i followed your instructions and also looked at  postcss documintation for other ideas  but I'm still getting the same error message